# Image segmentation for small images with rectangles

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I am doing toy project and trying to make image segmentation for rectangles generated in small images. Here the code:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import random
import cv2

GRID_SIZE = 32

def generate_image_and_mask(self):
    random.seed(100)
    #newIm = np.zeros((GRID_SIZE, GRID_SIZE, 3), np.uint8)
    img = Image.new('RGB', (GRID_SIZE, GRID_SIZE), color='black')
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)

    randX = random.randint(0, GRID_SIZE)
    randY = random.randint(0, GRID_SIZE)

    w = random.randint(0, GRID_SIZE)
    w = min(w, randX - GRID_SIZE)

    h = random.randint(0, GRID_SIZE)
    h = min(h, randY - GRID_SIZE)
    draw.rectangle([randX, randY, w, h,], fill='white')
    destBGR = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(img), cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    return destBGR, np.array(img.convert('L'))
```

Because of upsampling operation in the decoder rectangles corners look rounded( trained deeplabV3 model) :

[image: trained deeplabV3]

I can increase picture side from 32 to 1200 and it will looks good, but that is a bad solution. What do I need to do to get better rectangle mask for small images? How to change the network architecture? The same story is with other segmentation models, not only deep lab.